# What type of phrase is "Beyond a doubt" here?

Tags: phrases, parsing

> Beyond a doubt this man is honest.

"Beyond  a doubt" seems to be a phrase here and I believe it's a noun phrase,  but I'm told it's  not. Its a adverb phrase  how?

What is it?

Comment: Where did the quote come from? Who told you it’s not a noun phrase? Why do you think it is? Your question could be greatly improved if you did an edit and furnished those details.

Answer (score 1):

"Beyond a doubt" acts as adverb in that it modifies the adjective "honest."

The sentence means

"The man is certainly honest"

where an adverb replaces the phrase.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up your categorising of the phrase by it structure with the catagorising of the phrase as its function.

This is a *prepositional phrase*.  It is headed by the preposition "beyond".  The object of the preposition is a noun phrase, headed by the noun "doubt" (with the determiner "a").  This categorises the phrase based on its structure.

It can't be an adverb phrase, because there is no adverb to head the phrase.  It isn't a noun phrase, because it is headed by a preposition.

Prepositional phrases like this are optional adverbial elements in the sentence.  This categorises the phrase based on its function.

Notice the very big difference between "adverbial" and "adverb phrase".  Not the same thing at all.

Answer (score 0):

In classical parlance, it's a sentence adverbial. It gives the speaker's (here immovable) opinion about the truth of the statement in the (following) matrix sentence. I'd call it a pragmatic marker subclass modality (the word 'modal' here means 'addressing the speaker's view of the truth value of the attached proposition'). Compare 'Allegedly', 'Clearly', 'Arguably', 'Possibly' ....

Comment: since i am a beginner and English is a foreign language to me, what you mean here is, it modifies the meaning of adjective "honest" so its adverb or if you mean something else please dilute you sentence.

Comment: Consider the two-sentence extremely close paraphrase: 'The man is honest. There is no doubt about that.' This shows that 'Beyond a doubt,' is just a way of tacking on a comment from the speaker about how correct they believe the information in their matrix question to be (or how much they'd like the hearer to believe it's true!) So these modal additions refer to the (alleged truthfulness) of the statement in the matrix sentence. It's pointless saying they're an adverb or whatever – they're adjuncts.

Comment: By adjuncts you mean " adjective  conjunction".  If it is then it neither conjuncts the senescence nor adds any meaning to the subject man. What i am told is  "beyond a doubt"  is an adverb phrase  but i can't figure out how?

Comment: No. By _adjunct_ I mean the broadest definition given by [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/adjunct) '3c. part of a sentence that may be omitted without making the sentence ungrammatical'. CGEL deals comprehensively with these strings. / Some would call both variants 'Doubtlessly' / 'Beyond a doubt' in 'X[,] this man is honest' a 'sentence adverbial' as it contextualises the whole matrix sentence (as the two-sentence variant shows).  There's a traditional dustbin class for words that don't fit in any of the other well-recognised categories: they're all called 'adverbs'; phrases ...

Comment: doing the same jobs are grouped with these as 'adverbials' by the traditionalists. I prefer the grammars that treat 'sentence adverbials' as not really classifiable within the matrix sentence.